# GameOver Screen for a Memory game in Java

Tags: java

I am programming a Memory game in java and I want to make a GameOver-Screen with an image from the sprites folder (I already have the image for it and it is an image with .jpg) after all cards are flipped. So when all cards are flipped, the game is actually over and this GameOver-Screen appears. I have no idea how I can do that. The only thing I know is that it should start with `public void gameOver(){`. Probably it is possible to make something with "if()" and between the brackets you could say that the condition is that all cards are flipped.

```
// Memory.java
import ch.aplu.jgamegrid.*; // Imports the Library of Gamegrid, on which this code is based
import ch.aplu.util.*;


public class Memory extends GameGrid implements GGMouseListener {


    private boolean isReady = true;
    private MemoryCard card1;
    private MemoryCard card2;
    public Memory() {

        super(6, 6, 115, null, null, false);

        MemoryCard[] cards = new MemoryCard[36];

        for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {

            if (i < 18)
                cards[i] = new MemoryCard(i);
            else

                cards[i] = new MemoryCard(i - 18);

            addActor(cards[i], getRandomEmptyLocation());
            cards[i].show(1);
        }

        addMouseListener(this, GGMouse.lPress);

        // Application thread used to flip back cards 
        doRun();
        show();
        while (true) {
            // Wait until there is something to do
            Monitor.putSleep();
            delay(1000);
            // Flip cards back
            card1.show(1);
            card2.show(1);
            isReady = true;
            // Rearm mouse events
            setMouseEnabled(true);
        }
    }


    // imports the GGMouse package
    public boolean mouseEvent(GGMouse mouse) {

        Location location = toLocation(mouse.getX(), mouse.getY());
        MemoryCard card = (MemoryCard) getOneActorAt(location);

        // Card already flipped->no action
        if (card.getIdVisible() == 0)
            return true;
        // Show picture
        card.show(0);
        if (isReady) {
            isReady = false;
            card1 = card;
        } else {

            card2 = card;
            // Pair found, let them visible

            if (card1.getId() == card2.getId())
                isReady = true;
            else {
                // Disable mouse events until application thread flipped back cards
                setMouseEnabled(false);
                Monitor.wakeUp();
            }

        }
        return true;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Memory();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time a card is flipped, check if all cards have been flipped. Use a loop - you already have one in your code. For each index in the for loop... ie each card... check if getIdVisible() is 0.

If the card at index i is still hidden, return null and continue running your program is normal. However, if you get all the way through the loop, that means all cards are visible, which means you can call the gameOver() method, which shows the game over screen.

Does that sound like it fits with your program?

Edit:

To check if all cards are flipped, one thing you can do is to make MemeryCard[] cards (up in the constructor) a global variable. Then you can just call this method every time you reveal two cards:

```
public boolean areAllCardsFlipped() {

    // Start looking through each card
    for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {

        // We found a card that is NOT flipped. Stop here, because clearly all cards are not flipped.
        if (cards[i].getIdVisible() != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // We have looked at all cards, and we know that each one is flipped. We can return true.
    return true;
}
```

I'd say call this method in `mouseEvent()` before you return true for mouseEvent(), and if this returns true you can call the `gameOver()` method.

As for how to handle rendering the image... I don't know the api you're using for this game, so I can't tell you specifically how to do that. But at least with this code you should be able to trigger that gameOver.

Comment: So what exactly should I be adding in the code so that I can call the gameOver() method? And my second question is, how do I have to code the gameOver() method so that I can use an image from the sprites folder as the screen when the game is over?

Comment: I have implemented the code now, but there is a little problem. The modifiers at `public boolean areAllCardsFlipped(){` don't work and have to be removed (advice from the program). And the API i'm using is the JGameGrid.jar library I think.